# No webpage was found for the web address when trying to download file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have the following structure:

```
 AppName
    Content
       img
         file.png
```

I can navigate directly to `mysite.com/Content/img/file.png` without any issues.

However when I add `test.txt` to `img` and set to `Copy Always` and type `Content` (same as `file.png`), I get `No webpage was found for the web address` when visiting the link, when I want to be able to enable folks to download the publicly accessible file (no auth needed), just like the image.  Why isn't this working?

I can see `test.txt` in the `bin` folder of the app.  Does something else need to be configured to enable direct file downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your IIS site settings or web.config have mime type associated with .txt extension.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap

Comment: I am not able to get my images with the URL , I have .net core application, Please help me how to configure web.config , or what line I should put in web.config to get image through URL